# "C:/c/user/...my-folder/ isn't an existing directory" error

Tags: magit

I use Emacs 24.5.1 with [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) and added [Msys2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) to the exec-path to use git.exe

When I run 'Magit-status' I get the following error:

```
C:/c/user/...my-folder/ isn't an existing directory.
```

I can see there is something weird going on with the path. There is an extra '/c/'
There is a very similar error to users that use Git from Cygwin, and there is a work around to fix that by removing the extra '/cygdrive/' added to the file path. Unfortunately I haven't found anything to fix my problem.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Comment: IMO, if you're on Windows and you don't use Cygwin, you're just asking for a headache and a half. I use Emacs on Cygwin everyday at work.

Comment: "added Msys2 to the exec-path to use git.exe" you're trying to use the git from Msys2? How about... don't. Use [Git for Windows](https://msysgit.github.io/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I replaced Cygwin, Mingw and Git-for-Windows for Msys2 and never looked back. It works fast and flawlessly and it has everything the other 3 have. The one an only thing that doesn't work is Magit. If this problem can't be solved then I rather prefer to live without Magit :-)

Comment: @RafaelGP, FWIW, clearly, it does not work flawlessly, otherwise this question would not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a very similar error to users that use Git from Cygwin, and there is a work around to fix that by removing the extra '/cygdrive/' added to the file path.

The [existing workaround](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/1b467126f43a2f752b32299156c6772b12ca0c29/magit-git.el#L438-L441) that was recently added to `next` (see [magit issue #1318](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1318), commits ["work around a cygwin path issue"](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/2b4b366dde1c56496d46e033ff9e00c16aa1e2ed) and ["limit cygwin path kludge to non-cygwin Emacs with cygwin Git"](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/dab31162f44021e1889a8fefe6b33de1d1b09e5b)) works for Msys2 as well. So [installing the `next` branch](https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Installation#installing-from-the-next-branch) will fix the problem.

Here is a copy of the relevant function for easy reference:

```el
(defun magit-expand-git-file-name (filename &optional localname)
  (setq filename
        (if (file-name-absolute-p filename)
            (if localname
                filename
              (concat (file-remote-p default-directory) filename))
          (expand-file-name
           filename
           (and localname (file-remote-p default-directory 'localname)))))
  (if (and (eq system-type 'windows-nt) ; together with cygwin git, see #1318
           (string-match "^/\\(cygdrive/\\)?\\([a-z]\\)/\\(.*\\)" filename))
      (concat (match-string 2 filename) ":/"
              (match-string 3 filename))
    filename))
```

Comment: `C:/c/`?! Is this actually the default or does one have to actively misconfigure something to get there? By the way I would like to take this conversation to https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1318.

Comment: Oh, actually my windows machine had an older copy of magit, the existing workaround appears to work for msys2. The `C:/` part of `C:/c/` is added by Emacs when it tries to deal with `/c/user/...my-folder` returned by msys git.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!
@nanny Now Msys2 works flawlessly ;-)

Comment: @npostavs So I don't have to change that function at all?

Comment: @tarsius: yup, cygwin gives `/cygdrive/c/the/repo`, msys gives `/c/the/repo` and you already covered both.

Comment: Could you please have a look at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19536/why-do-paths-start-with-c-c-in-windows-emacs-when-i-use-next-error ?
I'm in a similar situation with compile-mode, but don't understand how to solve it...