# Why do paths start with "c:/c/..." in windows emacs when I use 'next-error'?

Tags: microsoft-windows, compilation-mode, path

I'm using native windows emacs together with mingw. When there's a compile error, the *compilation* buffer looks like this:

```
make -C ..
make: Entering directory `/c/Users/m.grunwald/Documents/Projects/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd'
compiling Update.c
../Source/Update.c: In function 'SetMessage':
../Source/Update.c:52:1: error: 'd' undeclared (first use in this     function)
 d
```

When I use `(next-error)`, emacs prompts me to "Find this error in...:" and the path it suggests is

```
c:/c/Users/m.grunwald/Documents/Projects/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/
```

Now this is neither a valid windows nor a valid mingw path and it makes compiling tideous. How do I get rid of the leading "C:" ?

Please note that the path that "make" prompts in the 2nd line is correct.

The linked topic ["C:/c/user/...my-folder/ isn't an existing directory" error](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12593/c-c-user-my-folder-isnt-an-existing-directory-error?lq=1) is about the same problem, but fixes it only in magit. I have no idea where I should tackle the problem for compile-mode and this is the wrong aproach, IMHO. It should be possible to fix this in emacs itself and only once, not once in each mode...

Comment: Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12593/c-c-user-my-folder-isnt-an-existing-directory-error, not sure offhand how to fix it for compilation mode though.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you do not mix native Windows Emacs with POSIX-y tools.

Comment: @nanny: Difficult. Emacs on cygwin works well, but is slow as molassis compared to the native one. I don't want to give up this speed!

Comment: @Markus In my opinion, it's definitely worth it to use Cygwin. Another alternative is to use an X server on Windows (e.g. VcXsrv) with Putty, and forward Emacs from a gnu/linux server.

Comment: maybe cygwin-mount.el would help? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Cygwin-paths.html

Comment: @npostavs: Thanks for the hint! It still doesn't work, however :( Using this package I get:
C:/cygwin64/c/Users/... and I don't see how to get rid of the "/c" which is what I really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like cygwin-mount.el only works for cygwin names.  Emacs already comes with `unmsys--file-name` to convert msys names, so I used it to write an msys file name handler for `expand-file-name` and `substitute-in-file-name` (it's unclear to me how to know which operations are important, so I just followed cygwin-mount.el's lead.  The code below seems to work for me).

```el
(defun msys-file-name-handler (operation &rest args)
  "Call `unmsys--file-name' on file names."
  (let ((inhibit-file-name-handlers
         (cons 'msys-file-name-handler
               (and (eq inhibit-file-name-operation operation)
                    inhibit-file-name-handlers)))
        (inhibit-file-name-operation operation))
    (pcase (cons operation args)
      (`(expand-file-name ,name . ,(or `(,directory) directory))
       (expand-file-name (unmsys--file-name name) (if directory (unmsys--file-name directory))))
      (`(substitute-in-file-name ,name)
       (substitute-in-file-name (unmsys--file-name name)))
      (_ (apply operation args)))))

(add-to-list 'file-name-handler-alist '("\\`/[a-zA-Z]/" . msys-file-name-handler))

;; Work around apparent bug in `compilation-parse-errors'.
(defun save-match-data-advice (fun &rest args)
  "Add this as `:around' advice to save the match-data."
  (save-match-data
    (apply fun args)))

(advice-add 'compilation-error-properties :around #'save-match-data-advice)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it breaks next-error and previous-error, if I include your code...

Comment: @Markus Oh, I had only tried applying the code after running `M-x compile`, it does indeed break subsequent compiles. It looks like a bug in the Emacs code that doesn't save match data; I've now added some advising code to the answer to work around it.

Comment: You, sir npostavs are my saviour! Since 1½ years I had to manually workaround this and now it works... thank you so much!